# Laravel 5.5 - How to change the Laravel log file name by remote IP?

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5.5

I am building an API PHP backend and I would like to create a log file for each IP connected to my API.

For example:

```
20171108__192.168.1.2__myapp.log
20171108__192.168.1.3__myapp.log
20171109__192.168.1.2__myapp.log
```

Could someone help me to approach this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel's logging use [Seldaek/monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), so you can create a new instance of the Logger for each request you get based on the user's ip.

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

/**
 * The function inside your controller.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request The request object.
 */
public function endpoint(Request $request){

    // Create the logger
    $logger = new Logger('my_logger');

    // Generate the file name (20171109__192.168.1.2__myapp.log)
    $filename = sprintf('%s/logs/%s__%s__myapp.log', storage_path(), date('Ymd'), $request->ip());

    // Add the handler
    $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($filename, Logger::DEBUG));

    // Use your logger
    $logger->info('My logger is ready');

}
```

Comment: @vlauciani Sure. Let me know how it goes :)